# assembly je not working/inferior 1 exit

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, flags

I'm working on an assignment using assembly and I've come across a problem in my code.

```
    .data
s:    string"-2"
      .text
      .global main

main: mov $s, %rax
      mov 0(%rax), %rbx

      cmp %0x2d, %bl
      je neg
      mov $1, %rcx
      ret

neg: mov 1(%rax), %rcx
     ret
```

When I reach 'je neg', I get the message: Inferior 1 (process 4302) exited with code 055. I am quite sure that my cmp works fine, since when i change je to jne it continues on to the next line. Does anyone know what my error is and how I can fix it? I just want to detect the minus sign and then 'remove' it by moving everything else to another register.

Thank you!

Comment: replace `%0x2d` with `$0x2d` or just `0x2d`?

Comment: Or, you know, `$'-'` for readability :)